# Delete rows all rows without a date in first cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to collect downloaded spreadsheets from my different banks, card suppliers, etc. and insert each of them in their own tab in a Google Sheets file. I then want to automate the job of arranging all these statements in same format (column-wise), import them to one common tab, and sort the common tab on date. The result will be one tab with all statements mixed in and sorted on date.

As part of this I need (for each individual tab) to be able to delete all rows not containing a date (format date...actually in the `dd.mm.yyyy`-format e.g. right-adjusted `04.10.2018` or any date format) in the "A"-column cell for that row. If format-search is difficult I could settle for a script that deletes all rows having any text (e.g. not start like 04 example over) or empty cell in "A" column.

Comment: I did ;-) I have nothing on deleting rows part.
But I take you're point and will try to code something as a start.

Comment: A better explanation is that I'm trying to learn this by recording macros then changing code to fit purpose in more detail. However, for deleting rows I've failed to find menu driven items to do the things I want to. For now I have short functions that does parts of what I want. I will sew them together when I have everything. But I have nothing on the deletion part.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

The hardest problem is figuring out what constitutes a date. If you would have googled that you would ultimately have run into your answer on stack overflow.  This is a simple script but I didn't test it.  So if it doesn't work, try debugging it.

```
function isADate(d){
  return (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === '[object Date]');
}

function delNonDatesInFirstCol(){
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  var n=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){//if you have a 1 header row start with var i=1;
    if(!vA[i][0] || !isADate(vA[i][0])){
      sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - n);
      n+=1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked just perfect "right out of the box". Thanks a lot!